# Docker container networking - interal ports open to everyone

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and have trouble setting up the network between the containers to not allow unnecessary connections from outside.

I have a Docker running on a VPS with three containers on a remote IP `123.xxx.xxx.xxx`

```
container name    published ports    IP adress
sqldb             3306:3306          172.xxx.xxx.4
applet1             80:3306          172.xxx.xxx.5
applet2           4444:4444          172.xxx.xxx.3
```

One is database and two are java apps. The trouble I am having right now is that when I create the containers the ports on the containers become exposed to the global internet so my database `sqldb` is exposed by `123.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306`

Right now ny java apps are connect through JDBC like so `jdbc:mysql://172.xxx.xxx.4:3306/db`.

I am trying to accomplish the following:
port 80 on host so `123.xxx.xxx.xxx` connects to java app `applet1`.

The goal is to give `applet1` the ability to connect to `sqldb` and also `applet2` but I don't wan't unecessary ports to be exposed to the whole internet. Preferably that internal URIs would be left but connections from outside (apart from SSH on port 22 and TCP on port 80) would be forbidden for ports 4444, 3306. Also, I don't yet know how to use `docker-compose` so if possible how can I solve it without it?

*I have heard you can connect to containers by writing container names like that: have not had success with it yet `jdbc:mysql://sqldb/db`.

Comment: If you don't want them to be exposed externally, don't expose them?

Comment: @tkausl, wait what? But how? Like, you run the command `docker run -d -p 4444:4444 image` so should I modify that somehow to like `docker run -d -p 4444 image`?

Comment: You shouldn't specify that port at all.

Comment: Will that generate internal URI adress like `172.xxx.xxx.4`? Or that is not needed?

Comment: It has a locally accessible IP-Address, yes, unless it was configured to not use the default network.

Answer (score 0):

If all your containers are running on the same [docker bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/), you don't need to expose any ports for them to communicate with each other.

Docker Compose is a particularly good tool for organising several containers like this as it automatically configures a network for you

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml

version: '3.9'
services:
  sqldb:
    image: sqldb
  applet1:
    image: applet1
    ports:
      - '80:3306' # you sure about this container port?
    depends_on:
      - sqldb
  applet2:
    image: applet2
    depends_on:
      - sqldb
```

Now only your `applet1` container will have a host port mapping. Both applets will be able to connect to any other service within the network on their container ports.